# Unknown WebSocket (SockJS) on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, sockjs

I've deployed a React app running on NodeJS to the google app engine and everything works well. However, when I load the main page, I get a WebSocket error (failed handshake) that occurs 15s later, probably due to a timeout. The thing is, I don't use SockJS in my app at all so I suspect the app engine makes use of it. Note that this error happens both while loading through HTTP and HTTPS.
It does not break anything but the user can see that the browser is waiting for the page to load entirely, which is bothering.

Why is this socket used? Can I turn it off?

Here is the error stack:

```
websocket.js:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://*****.appspot.com/sockjs-node/514/vrdqxoct/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
WebSocketBrowserDriver @ websocket.js:6
WebSocketTransport @ websocket.js:32
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._connect @ main.js:219
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._receiveInfo @ main.js:193
g @ emitter.js:30
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-receiver.js:67
g @ emitter.js:30
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-ajax.js:37
g @ emitter.js:30
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
xhr.onreadystatechange @ abstract-xhr.js:124
```

EDIT:
As requested, here is my package.json and webpack.config.js.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "*****",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-apollo": "^1.4.16",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-middleware": "^0.1.21",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.73.1",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "font-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
import path from 'path';

export default {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './src/index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `webpack-dev-server` to serve the requests?

Comment: Which request? This WebSocket connection isn't something I initiate in my application. That being said, yes I use `webpack` but not `webpack-dev-server` (maybe the app engine uses it?)

Comment: Can you put your `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` in the question? You will have socket connections if you use webpack-dev-server for hot reloading of the code.

Comment: I added the requested files to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, this is due to `webpack`.

This is the script that runs for `react-scripts start` [start script](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js).

If you look at the code, it internally uses `webpack-dev-server`. If you find the default config for `webpack-dev-server` ([here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js)), the default config has **HOT RELOADING** enabled by default. Hence you see socket connections created to enable **HOT RELOADING**.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I made changes to deploy a built version of my app to the engine and that solved it.